# C++: Can t get sockets, threads and structures to work

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, structure

Im currently trying to learn how sockets and threads work, to this end, I started writing a program to make some kind of chat room:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct par {
    SOCKET* s;
    string* buffer;
    bool keep = 1;
};

struct HANDLES {
    HANDLE hRecv;
    HANDLE hSend;
};

unsigned int WINAPI recvThread(LPVOID param) {
    par* data = (par*)param;
    char* inBuf;
    unsigned short int inSize;
    string aux = inBuf;
    string* auxptr = data->buffer;
    SOCKET* s = data->s;
    while(true) {
        inSize = recv(*s, inBuf, 2000, 0);
        inBuf[inSize] = '\0';
        *auxptr = aux; // ???
    }
}

unsigned int WINAPI sendThread(LPVOID param) {
    par* data = (par*)param;
    string auxBuf = "NULL";
    string* auxptr = data->buffer;
    SOCKET* s = data->s;
    while (true) {
        if(auxBuf != (*auxptr)) {
            string auxstring = *auxptr;
            const char* auxchar = auxstring.c_str();
            send(*s, auxchar, strlen(auxchar), 0);
            auxBuf = auxstring;
        }
        Sleep(200);
    }
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    string buf = "NULL";
    vector<HANDLES> hVec;

    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in server;

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(s, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));

    listen(s, 5);

    sockaddr_in clientdir;
    int siz = sizeof(clientdir);
    SOCKET cliente;
    while((cliente = accept(s, (sockaddr*)&clientdir, &siz))) {
        par* newParams;
        newParams->s = &cliente;
        newParams->buffer = &buf;
        if(cliente != INVALID_SOCKET) {
            HANDLES aux;
            aux.hRecv = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, recvThread, (void*)newParams, 0, 0);
            aux.hSend = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, sendThread, (void*)newParams, 0, 0);
            hVec.push_back(aux);
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem that it encounters appears in: newParams->s = &cliente;
Making the server crash.
I would appreciate if anybody could tell me what I m doing wrong and any other fixes that should be implemented.

Comment: `newParams` is not initializes and therefore you can't just use it in the next line `newParams->s`... and next time, please - attach the error you recieve

Answer (score 0):

The *first* problem is that you have an uninitialized pointer (`newParams`) that doesn't point anywhere valid. This you then use and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

When you fix the above (by allocating a new `par` structure with `new` and pointing `newParams` to that object) you have *another* problem: The pointers to the `SOCKET` and `string` members in the structure. All pointers, no mather how many (or few) connections and threads you have will all point to the ***same*** `SOCKET` or `string`.

If the receive and send thread should share the `SOCKET` and `string` then instead of having those members being pointer, they are values that are copied as or when needed, but the thread share the *structure*, which is solved by passing the same `newParams` pointer to both threads.

There are also many more problems with uninitialized pointers, and also with data races (since you don't protect the resources the thread shares).

My advice is to take a few steps back, and scrap *all* of your code. And then re-code it while taking small baby-steps, adding one little bit at a time while making sure it works, and that you understand *how* it works. [Rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) as well as using an actual debugger greatly helps. And reading books. And practicing. And not rushing and try to do everything at once.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the pointers mistake and took your advice and scraped the code. Now it is working.